# Errors converting HTML to XML or HTML with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

My HtmlAgilityPack version is 1.3.0. My example:

```
StringBuilder sbXml = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sbXml);
XmlTextWriter tw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
HtmlWeb htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
htmlWeb.LoadHtmlAsXml("http://finance.qq.com/a/20121126/000974.htm", tw);
richTextBox1.Text = sbXml.ToString();
```

Error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: the length  is not less than  0。(tw is  null)

Why has the HTML of this URL problems?

Comment: what line does this throw?

Comment: Find the error using binary search: Cut out half of the document to see in which half the error is. Iterate this.